# how to show some markers on a static image using openlayers 3

Tags: image, openlayers-3, marker

I am trying to show some marker on the static image ie

Given a static image of certain size in feet and set of point in feets how mark some image or a marker on the static image using openlayers3

I understand we have a provision in  openlayer3 to use the static image as the base layer of the map

I am not getting how to show the marker on the static image(base layer)for given certain plots on the image

Any help would be more thank you please suggest a war to do it

I am show the static image as the map as shown below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Static image example</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.6.0/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.6.0/ol.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div id="map" class="map"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<script>
    // Map views always need a projection.  Here we just want to map image
    // coordinates directly to map coordinates, so we create a projection that uses
    // the image extent in pixels.
    var extent = [0, 0, 1024, 968];
    var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
        code: 'xkcd-image',
        units: 'pixels',
        extent: extent
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Image({
                source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
                    attributions: [
                        new ol.Attribution({
                            html: '&copy; <a href="http://xkcd.com/license.html">xkcd</a>'
                        })
                    ],
                    url: 'colorful-triangles-background.jpg',
                    projection: projection,
                    imageExtent: extent
                })
            })
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            projection: projection,
            center: ol.extent.getCenter(extent),
            zoom: 2
        })
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But i have no idea how to plot the markers the plots are json given to plot is some thing like below

[{
x:1.234,
y:3.34,
units:feet
},
{
x:2.234,
y:4.34,
units:feet
},
{
x:7.234,
y:9.34,
units:feet
}]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Create an Icon Style
- Create Icon Feature
- Setup a New Vector layer with vector source
- Add the vector layer in Map's layer
- I have displayed the marker on click of the map at mouse position, you can add markers on the event you want
- Also since I did not have the images you were referring I have referred the open layer examples image.

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title>Static image example</title>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com   /bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.6.0/ol.css" type="text/css">
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.6.0/ol.js">    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
      <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script>
      // Map views always need a projection.  Here we just want to map     image
      // coordinates directly to map coordinates, so we create a projection that uses
      // the image extent in pixels.
      var extent = [0, 0, 1024, 968];
      var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
          code: 'xkcd-image',
          units: 'pixels',
          extent: extent
      });


  var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Icon(({
          anchor: [15, 24],
          size: [32, 48],
          anchorXUnits: 'pixels',
          anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
          opacity: 0.75,
          src: 'http://www2.psd100.com/ppp/2013/11/0501/Map-marker-icon-1105213652.png'
      }))
  });


  //Create a Feature
   var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
          geometry: new ol.geom.Point([72.5800, 23.0300])

      });

  //Setup a Vector Source
  var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
      features: [iconFeature]
  });

  //Setup a Vector Layer
  var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: vectorSource
  });

  iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);


  var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
      new ol.layer.Image({
          source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
              attributions: [
                  new ol.Attribution({
                      html: '&copy; <a href="http://xkcd.com/license.html">xkcd</a>'
                  })
              ],
              url: 'http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/online_communities.png',
              projection: projection,
              imageExtent: extent
          })
      }), vectorLayer //Add Vector in layers
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
      projection: projection,
      center: ol.extent.getCenter(extent),
      zoom: 2
  })
  });

  //On Map click setup marker
   map.on('click', function (evt) {

      var feature = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(evt.coordinate));
      feature.setStyle(iconStyle);
      vectorSource.clear();
      vectorSource.addFeature(feature);
      selectedlong = evt.coordinate[0];
      selectedlat = evt.coordinate[1];

  });

  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

Comment: thank you so much but i did same using angular directive https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-openlayers-directive please check that as well for refernce

Comment: Thanks. I am glad that you have got the solution for your query.